# unknown border in chrome input

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a search input with a strange border. I've  already tried removing the outline, shadow, :focus and :active styles and got no results.

This only happens on Chrome. On Firefox and Safari the border's not there.

Here's a screenshot - http://d.pr/i/yPNo - and here's the code I'm using -  http://jsfiddle.net/3CDcV/

Comment: The jsfiddle code appears to render correctly on chrome/mac 20.0.1132.47

Comment: Not in my chrome can you help me ?

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? I cannot tell from the screen shot, but it appears that there may be an element over the input element itself, where the input element has the correct rounded borders, but the other element is eclipsing portions of the borders.

Comment: my chrome version 20.0.1132.4 and at the jsfiddle i made it looks the same as the screenshot.

Comment: I can replicate this issue on Chrome 22.0.1201.0 Canary.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
input[type="search"]{
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    height:25px;
    width:150px;
    background:#181818;
    border:1px solid #0e0e0e;
    padding-left:5px;
    color:#666;
    font-size:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  1px 1px 0px 1px #202020;
    box-shadow:  1px 1px 0px 1px #202020;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;

    -moz-appearance:none;
   -webkit-appearance:none;
}  ​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CDcV/4/)

Comment: And a short article about why those two extra properties are necessary: http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/